# Missing mapping in di.xml after upgrading 2.4.0 to 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

The app breaks completely after upgrading a working 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 using instructions from https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html.

Steps:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

`setup:upgrade` errors out with the following message, and the entire M2 instance (web and CLI) is broken.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi\Model\GetEntitiesInterface in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Upon inspecting `app/etc/di.xml`, I see no mapping for `Magento\MediaContentSynchronizationApi\Model\GetEntitiesInterface`.

It seems to me the composer require and update does not update `di.xml` correctly, but I'm not sure. Any idea how to upgrade to 2.4.1?

Comment: I also have this issue. I'll let you know if I find a fix

Comment: Can you please explain this ? Which command one by one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is related to the ElasticSearch requirement and it not being properly setup during the upgrade.

I found it best to just:
Before you pull down latest code and run setup:upgrade, disable all ElasticSearch:

```
php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
```

Then get latest code, perform the setup:upgrade and visit admin; make sure all works.  Then enable ElasticSearch but ignore the setup:upgrade.  Go into Admin and properly setup the ES; then save.  Now all will work.

Sometimes php bin/magento will not work because of that, so it is neccesary to disable ES modules manually from app/config.php and then flush the cache manually

If you tried this and still get the error; make sure that when you disabled the ES; that you completely flushed all cache (and any redis) and deleted any generated files etc.

Answer (score 4):

Clear Redis Cache is helpful to me

redis-cli flushall

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you got caches set up (PHP OPCache, Redis, etc.), the configuration cache data may end up interfering with the new code.

The bulletproof way to deal with issues like this is to disable configuration cache prior to `di:compile`.

Another gotcha, is disabling config cache with `php ./bin/magento cache:disable` might likewise fail because `./bin/magento` errors with similar messages.

So to resolve this *reliably*, you would resort to things like `sed` to disable config cache:

```
# important step: disable general config cache with sed!
sed -i "s@'config' => 1@'config' => 0@" ./app/etc/env.php

# disables remaining caches
php ./bin/magento cache:disable

# compilation
php ./bin/magento setup:di:compile

# re-enable back all the caches
php ./bin/magento cache:enable
```

P.S. all in all, this is a design flaw of Magento 2. `di:compile` should not be using any caches, but, alas, it does, and thus this crucial step of Magento deployment is very much faulty unless caches are disabled prior to running it.

Comment: Are there any other types of cache that should just be kept disabled to make quality of life easier?

Comment: The ones which can directly affect `di:compile` and even deploy static assets are the mentioned general config cache, and also PHP OPCache (if `opcache.validate_timestamps=Off` only). Disabling other caches - I haven't had the time to check if it's actually required, so running `php ./bin/magento cache:disable` is the precautionary step that might not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing Redis Cache helped for me.